# find command line argument path

Tags: linux, find

Can someone explain what `find -path` means?

I tried looking at the man page, but I do not understand why it works the way it does with the script I wrote.

`find ! -path . -type d -printf '%T@ %P\n' | sort -nr | head -n3 | awk '{print $2}'`

This returns to me the last three modified directories in the current folder Im in. However, when I remove the `-path .` it only returns files to me, instead of folders. It's almost as if `-type d` is ignored.

Answer (score 1):

If you remove the `-path .` but keep the `!` at the start, then `-type d` is not ignored, your condition is `! -type d`, which means "not directory". SO you get what you ask for.

Comment: Ah so, ```! -path .``` is simply ignoring the current directory i.e. ```.```?

Comment: Yes, exactly, ignore `.`.

Answer (score 0):

The command you are trying will ignore the current folder with the argument `! -path .`. Since you removed only `-path .` the not-operator `!` will apply to the succeeding argument, `-type d`.

The result is that `find` will ignore all directories in the find path.